# Change the title of Solution Explorer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

My job forces me to work in Visual Studio and .NET. I'm attempting to streamline the experience, somewhat successfully. (TFS still thwarts me.)

Right now, I want to work with multiple Solution Explorers, as we have a Visual Studio solution containing a multitude of csproj files. Creating a new Solution Explorer view for each commonly-used project would be great, except for this - all of the tabs and titles say "Solution Explorer".

Is there any way to change the title of the Solution Explorer window and tab? Is there any way to set the title to the title of the root solution or project file? (If there's an extension that will do this, I will happily install it.)

Thank you.

**Edit:** It looks like my question wasn't understood very well. The project conforms to regular standards - it's one *Solution* with multiple *Projects*, with a highly-nested directory structure. Basically, instead of having to scroll a lot, and constantly open and close nodes in the tree view, I'd like to have multiple Solution Windows to help facilitate this. Visual Studio provides an option called `New Solution Explorer View` in the context menu, which will open a new Solution Explorer window with a target object at its root. I want to do this for the commonly-used projects in my solution, but I want each Explorer instance to be named so that I can keep them in a single pane and click between them. Make sense?

Hope I've appeased the VS enthusiasts.

**Double Edit:** [This](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3390915-named-solution-explorer-views) is the feature I'm looking for. Is this possible through an extension?

Comment: are you trying to create multiple projects under a single solution...? if so this is not that trivial `Google works wonders if it's ever used properly` [MSDN Multi-Project Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/23x5fk78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: why do you need to rename solution explorer, if the content inside is a different ? or you have same content from different branches ?

Comment: What you call "streamline" is obviously changing good practises when it comes to developing with .NET. Unless you work in a one man show, learn and adopt rather than try to change. Otherwise, all your team mates who have to develop alongside you and future generations to come to maintain your software will have to learn your special way of developing software using VS.

Comment: This might possibly make sense if you explain why a single solution containing multiple projects (in the traditional way of Visual Studio) does not give you the functionality you think you want.

Comment: @MethodMan I don't think you understood the request. I've edited the question.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst The project follows standard .NET practices. Please don't assume that I'm attempting to change them. This is an IDE question dealing with workspace setup, nothing more.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Reading your edit I take my comment back. Good question, but I'm afraid there's a simple trick. What you definitely could do is writing an extension that has the same behaviour as the Solution Explorer, but comes with the naming option ;-)

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying. Did you ever solve this? Scrolling back and forth between frequently used folders is cumbersome. Having separate Solution Explorer View tabs makes it much easier to navigate but they all have the same title.

Comment: @cpg Nope, still the same shitty Visual Studio situation. Blegh.

Comment: Vote me in on this question - if you need to rally votes, I'm with you - I also need this feature for me me and many other developers

Answer (score 2):

There exists a visual studio-extension named **Multiple Solution Explorer Tools**, which extends the default behavior of the *New Solution Explorer View*-command:

[Multiple Solution Explorer Tools Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misaz.multiplesolutionexplorertools)

- New Solution Explorer instances gets persisted across solution unload and load.
- The toolbar provides an icon ([image: Toolbar icon for solution explorer view renaming]) to rename the current solution explorer view.

The extension currently supports Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.