# Changing the title of the Solution Explorer tool window in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

In visual studio, in the Solution Explorer you can right clock and select "New Solution Explorer from here"
[image]
Then a new Solution explorer tool window open - but it has the same name "Solution Explorer" - and no way to reflect the folder it represents or anything.

If I want to use multiple solution explorer windows - it'll be best if I can determine a name for them - or if their name would be representative of the root item they refer to.

Is there a visual studio extension that does that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461703/change-the-title-of-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the title value via the property named caption. Here is a simple demo for your reference.

```
 DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            List<Window> list = new List<Window>();
            foreach (Window w in dte.Windows)
            {
                if (w.Caption == "Solution Explorer")
                {
                    list.Add(w);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                list[i].Caption = "Test" + i;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: First of all - cool - I love that demo it's exactly what I needed - now I just need to write a vs extension that'll get that done. 

If only there was an existing extension that does this....

Thanks so much

Comment: you need to write a vs extension to achieve it. here is the simple demo for your reference. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQKfg1ecRqovTyMW

Comment: Thank you for your approval, but it is out of our support scope, if you encounter the any other issue on devloping the vsx project, please create a new thread, we'll try our best to resolve it. 
If the reply is helpful, please mark it an answer, it will be benifical to other communites.

Comment: Got it - thanks for your support - I appreciate the great help

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly get the solution explorer window as follows and update the name:

```
(dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer)).Caption = "Foo"
```